# Can I use Stitch with multiple Xero accounts?

Tags: xero-api, stitch

Stitch is an ETL that provides an integration with Xero accounting software:
https://www.stitchdata.com/integrations/xero/

I intended to use Stitch to allow the users of my app to connect their account with Xero, allowing us to store their Xero information for later analysis.

I was wondering if there is a way of setting and managing multiple Xero accounts with the same Stitch account, programatically (via an API, not via a UI).

I have seen the docs and they explain how to manually connecting your Stitch account with your (one) Xero account by manually authorizing:
https://www.stitchdata.com/docs/integrations/saas/xero#add-stitch-data-source

But I need to support multiple Xero accounts and to be able to set them up through my program.

Answer (score 1):

the Xero API does support this. However depending on how the Stitch XeroAPI integration is setup they may only be allowing access to one org at a time. If you do request this feature and they decide to add it, we will work closely with them on the XeroAPI side.

Good luck. If you decide to build some kind of integration yourself shoot us a message at api@xero.com and we will help you through.

Comment: Thank you! But I was asking if Stitch supported it